# count rows which has specific value in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have used jquery datatable to present my data in table. All works fine I just have an issue. My table has column which shows Active & Inactive customers. I want to make a count of active & inactive customers for which I have following script. In this I am trying to count a rows which has active value in each row but it counts total number of rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').dataTable({
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "paging": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" ,                    //For Different Paging  Style
                "scrollY": 400,                                     // For Scrolling
                "jQueryUI": false,                                     //Enabling JQuery UI(User InterFace)
                "lengthMenu": [[30, 50, 100, -1], [30, 25, 50, "All"]],
                drawCallback: function (settings) {
                    var api = this.api(); 
                    // get the number of rows, but remove the page:current if you want number of rows in entire dataset
                    var count = api.rows({
                        api: $('#example tbody tr td[value="active"]')
                    }).data().length;
                    // this takes the count and appends it in a span tag to the dataTables pageinate div element
                    $('<span id="active_rows"></span>').html(count + ' rows').appendTo($('.dataTables_info'));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .filter() for the filtering of the rows you want to count. Here below an example of how to use the .filter() . I have also added links to the information page of the option and to a forum post with almost the same question.

```
var count = api.rows
            .column( 0 ) 
            .data()
            .filter( function (value, index) {
                  return value="active" ? true : false;
            }).length;
```

- https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()
- https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/41496